# Grant LOCK TABLES to databases starting with word 'test' using bash script

Tags: mysql, bash, ansible, sql-grant

I am trying to grant the test_user access to any mysql databases on a server that begin with 'test'

No matter what I try I cannot get this to work and I keep getting different errors.

I am able to run select and show statments fine using bash but I think the wildcard with this is cuasing issues??

Any help is much appreciated, different things I have ran are below with the errors too (I have tried running in both single and double quotes

```
$mysql -u$user -p$pass -S $SOCK -e "use mysql; GRANT LOCK TABLES ON ``test\%``.* TO 'test_user'@'%';"
        
       "ERROR at line 1: Unknown command '\\%'.\nERROR at line 1: Unknown command '\\%'.",

$mysql -u$user -p$pass -S $SOCK -e "use mysql; GRANT LOCK TABLES ON `test\%`.* TO 'test_user'@'%';"

        "/bin/sh: line 38: test%: command not found",
        "ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '* TO 'test_user'@'%'' at line 1",

$mysql -u$user -p$pass -S $SOCK -e "use mysql; GRANT LOCK TABLES ON test\%.* TO 'test_user'@'%';"

        "ERROR at line 1: Unknown command '\\%'.",


$mysql -u$user -p$pass -S $SOCK -e 'use mysql; GRANT LOCK TABLES ON `test`\%.* TO 'test_user'@'%';'

        "ERROR at line 1: Unknown command '\\%'.\nERROR at line 1: Unknown command '\\%'.",

$mysql -u$user -p$pass -S $SOCK -e 'use mysql; GRANT LOCK TABLES ON 'test'\%.* TO 'test_user'@'%';'

        "ERROR at line 1: Unknown command '\\%'.\nERROR at line 1: Unknown command '\\%'.",
```

Comment: You cannot provide a pattern to match all tables starting with test in the grant statement, you need to list those tables explicitly one by one. You can use information_schema.tables view to generate a list of such tables, though.

Comment: But I can log onto the mysql instance and run 
```GRANT LOCK TABLES ON `test%`.* TO 'test_user'@'%';```
and that works

Comment: SInce you have tagged this with Ansible, In the past I've used something like `shell: cmd: "mysql -uroot -p{{ SQL_ROOT_PASSWORD }} -e\"GRANT ... ON *.* TO {{ TEST_USER }}@{{ TEST_IP }} REQUIRE SSL;\" -N -B"`. Please take note that I've escaped the quotes from the mysql execute option. And wouldn't it be better to use the mysql module?

Answer (score 1):

I got it working, in case anyone wants to know how I did it:

```sh
$mysql -u$user -p$pass -S $SOCK -NBe 'use mysql; GRANT LOCK TABLES ON `test%`.* TO `test_user`@`%`;'
```

test%, test_user & % all needed to be surrounded by back ticks, nothing else required escaping

Thanks